# Neo4J as OLAP performance benchmark

Tags: olap, neo4j

I would like to know if Neo4J can be used as OLAP. The search says it is great tool as OLTP. However there are no proven case studies as OLAP.

Also only Jasper 1st version of connector with Neo4J. I have not seen any connectors from other BI providers. If there are any BI providers that have auto connector with Neo4J please share.

Answer (score 0):

[Reportsanywhere](http://www.reportsanywhere.com) has a [Neo4j connector](http://www.reportsanywhere.com/pebble/2010/05/30/creating_a_report_for_a_neo4j_sample_database.html) and understands graphs.

If your OLAP model can be described as a graph, then Neo4j is very suitable.